# Magento - Get Configurable Product Available Sizes

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm trying to get all the available sizes of my configurable product inside the list.phtml grid.

With the code below I can succesfully get all the sizes, but it show even the not available sizes.

```
    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="taglie">
    <?php $cProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
    //check if product is a configurable type or not
    if ($cProduct->getData('type_id') == "configurable") {
        //get the configurable data from the product
        $config = $cProduct->getTypeInstance(true);
        //loop through the attributes
        foreach($config->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($cProduct) as $attributes) { ?>
            <?php foreach($attributes["values"] as $values) {
                echo "<span>".$values["label"]."</span>";
            } ?> 
        <?php 
        } 
    } ?>
</div>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $this->__('Out of Stock') ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What I'm trying to do is hide the not available sizes option.

Answer (score 1):

```
<p style="margin-top: 8px;">    
    <?php 
        $sizes = array();
        if($_product->isConfigurable()){
            $allProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts(null, $_product);
            foreach ($allProducts as $subproduct) {
                if ($subproduct->isSaleable()) {
                    $sizes[] = $subproduct->getAttributeText('size');
                }
            }
            if(count($sizes)>0) {
            echo implode(", ", $sizes);
            }
        }
    ?>
</p>
```